# How do I apply a template to my single posts?

Tags: posts, page-template, css

(I am using a child theme of twenty-ten)

For most of my pages I like to use the single column template. I noticed that (after I updated to 3.14) my single posts were using the default template (which has a sidebar for widgets).

How do I get rid of this?

I could style the sidebar away but is there a way to tell WP to apply the single-column template for my single-posts? Note that the main blog page applies the single-column template to it, so this is only happening when I bring up individual posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could duplicate the single-column template and rename it single.php.